# Python merge multiple dicts with common keys, generating new keys for the respective source dict

Tags: python, list

Is there an elegant way in python to go from

```
d1 = {"key1": ["a", "b"], "key2": ["c", "d"]}  
d2 = {"key1": ["e", "f"], ...}
```

to:

```
dd =
[
   { "old_key": "key1",
     "d1_key": ["a", "b"],
     "d2_key": ["e", "f"]
   },
   { "old_key": "key2",
     "d1_key": ["c", "d"]
   }
]
```

I'm not fussed if there is a `d2_key: ""` if there exists no `old_key` in `d2`

EDITED: from pseudo code

Comment: Your `dd` structure is not valid Python, actually none of your code is.

Comment: it is pseudo code - I have found quite an elegant solution courtesy of a colleague (see post)

Comment: Also, save for the abuse of inverted commas everywhere it is a valid python structure

Comment: No, is not, `dd` would be a set? with a list inside (curly braces and brackets), again no valid Python. Also what is `a`?

Comment: I've edited it to not include pseudo code, I had hoped this was obvious, Stragas managed it. Just trying to engage with the community and I think this is a valid question that hasn't been asked elsewhere. Would have been nice if you could have contributed solutions like other more friendly members did in stead of vote down and pick apart minor irrelevant detail. Happy Friday to you

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of a very helpful colleague I think have a solution I think solves it. The union operation is something I have never used/considered before.

```
all_keys = (d1.keys() | d2.keys())
dd = []
for key in all_keys:
    dd.append({"old_key": key,
               "d1_key": d1.get(key, ""),
               "d2_key": d2.get(key, "")})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
dd = list()
for k, v in d1.items():
    temp_dict = dict()
    temp_dict["old_key"] = k
    temp_dict["d1_"+k] = v
    if k in d2.keys():
        temp_dict["d2_"+k] = d2[k]
    dd.append(temp_dict)
```

Beware that this will ignore all the keys that are in d2 but not in d1 for if they are neccesary you can also add this for loop afterwards:

```
for k, v in d2.items():
    temp_dict = dict()
    if k not in d1.keys():
        temp_dict["d2_" + k] = d2[k]
    dd.append(temp_dict)
```